# PROLOG Stack overflow recursive multiply

Tags: prolog

```
multiply(A,0,0).
multiply(A,B,C) :- D is B-1, multiply(A,D,E), C is E+A.
```

After using this rule once and Prolog returns an answer, if I want it to continue searching (prompts A = 5 ? and I hit ;), Prolog crashes. I don't understand why? Would anyone be able to explain. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you do `multiply(5,-1,X)`?

Comment: You didn't say with which arguments you are calling your predicate. In Prolog, it's a very important part of the specification which combinations of bound/unbound arguments you expect to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is,

`multiply(A,B,C) :- D is B-1, multiply(A,D,E), C is E+A.`

This code does not have the constraint `B > 0` that would prevent the stack overflow from occurring.

You can modify the code as,

`multiply(A,B,C) :- B > 0, D is B-1, multiply(A,D,E), C is E+A.`

Also, this line `multiply(A,0,0).` gives a singleton warning, so you can possibly change it into `multiply(_,0,0)`

**Note** : I wrote the constraint `B > 0` thinking that you call the predicate as `multiply(5,1,A)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can make an endless loop easily:

```
?- [user].
|: loop(0). 
|: loop(X) :- X0 is X - 1, loop(X0).
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- loop(3).
true ;
```

After you redo (when you press `;`) you backtrack into the second clause with a 0.

Then `X0` becomes -1, you go into the recursive `loop(X0)`, and from here on the first clause will never again match.

Try for example querying:

```
?- loop(-1).
```

Your version of the infinite loop is not tail-recursive, which means that it will use up the stack eventually. Here is a minimal example:

```
?- [user].
|: out_of_stack(0, 0).
|: out_of_stack(X, Y) :- X0 is X - 1, out_of_stack(X0, Y0), Y is Y0 + 1.
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- out_of_stack(3, R).
R = 3 ;
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 1.0Gb, global: 19Kb, trail: 1Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 11,183,864, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 3
ERROR:   Possible non-terminating recursion:
ERROR:     [11,183,864] user:out_of_stack(-11183853, _5046)
ERROR:     [11,183,863] user:out_of_stack(-11183852, _5066)
```

So this is what is happening and why Prolog crashes.

To get rid of the problem, do as other have suggested. The other solution is to use `0`, `s(0)`, `s(s(0))`, ... to represent natural numbers.